# Xaml and DataGrid and Databinding Issues

Tags: wpf, xaml

Given a view-model with public writeable properties SelectedItem and SelectedIndex, it would be nice to be able to do the following:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ...
```

Then the view-model would easily know what item is currently selected. Unfortunately, this does not work (Notification occurs once, at start-up). Why?

The following does consistently notify the view-model,

```
<DataGrid SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" ...
```

Unfortunately, the "index" value is actually relatively to the filtered and sorted ICollectView which wraps the underlying collection (Why). ICollectionView does not have a index property my initial attempts at accessing it directly triggered a stack-overflow (no pun intended).

I suspect there are good reasons for these "gotchas" in the current Xaml implementation. It may even be due to the fact that I am using an F#/Xaml template.

Answer (score 0):

OK. The problem turned out to be a type issue. Essentially, I had defined an option property in the view-model that was being consumed by WPF as an object. While WPF was accommodating this translation, it seems, the event notifications back to F# was being ignored, though it occurred at start-up.

The problem was resolved when I meticulous ensured that the exposed property was indeed an object in the F# view-model.

```
  member x.SelectedMember         
    with get() = 
      match selectedMember with
      | Some m -> m :> obj
      | _ -> null
    and set (v:obj) =
      selectedMember <- 
        match v with
        | :? MemberVM as m -> Some m
        | _ -> None
      x.OnPropertyChanged "SelectedMember"
```

The correct code is a lot more verbose than my original incorrect code version. If I had more of this translation perhaps I would write a pair of generic Option <-> Object maps...